# Java: crawl numbers

Tags: java, web-crawler

I created a java phonebook (desktop app) , on my pc there's a program that outputs the number of the caller. it's an 8 digits number.

here's how it works[image]

I want to crawl only 8 digits numbers from the popup, so lets say this is a popup:

```
    My name is someone like you, i am 22 years old, i was born in 19/10/1989,
    my phone number is 34544512
    my brother is someone like me he is 18 years old, born in 9101993 
    his number is 07777666
```

in this example, i want to crawl **07777666** and **34544512** only.

I want to check the popup window every 2s for new numbers, if a caller calls me twice, his number will be already stored my db and if not I'll store

**Note:** if that's can't be done, then forget about the popup, lets say it's just a **text** being updated every 2 seconds, how to crawl it

This not a homework lol :D

Comment: Using regex? Why would you not support anything different  than 8 dig. number with no spaces? check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Comment: @hovanessyan phone numbers in my country are created from 8 digits so i only need to get them

Comment: yeah but some people may type them with spaces-in groups, with dashes, including international code (using + sign) etc...

Comment: @hovanessyan good point, well at least i don't want to crawl numbers that have less than 8 digits then :D

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou check out my snippet, it takes care of 8 or more digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java regular expressions. Create a regex of 8 or more digits and use it. You will be able to extract these 2 phone numbers from your text sample.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String testString = "My name is someone like you, i am 22 years old, i was born in 19/10/1989,"
                          + " my phone number is  34544512 3454451266"
                          + " my brother is someone like me he is 18 years old, born in 9101993 "
                          + " his number is 07777666";

        String[] pieces = testString.split("\\s+");
        String expression = "\\d{8,}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            if (pattern.matches(expression, pieces[i]))
                System.out.println(pieces[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do the splitting business - you can use Matcher.find() and a regex like `"\\b(\\d{8})\\b"`

Answer (score 1):

Haha... this is so obviously a homework exercise that you're cheating on!

Your professor probably expects you to use regular expressions.  If that's over your head, then just tokenize the strings and check each token with `Long.parseLong()`.

Of course, both of these approaches assume that the data will be *exactly* like your example above, and not have dashes in the phone numbers.  If you need to account for dashes (or dots, spaces, etc), then the regex or manual logic gets pretty complex pretty quickly.

UPDATE:  If you ***do*** need to account for phone numbers with dashes or other characters in them, I would probably:

1. tokenize the string,
2. iterate through all tokens, using regex to remove all non-numeric characters, and finally
3. use regex (or `Long.parseLong()` and `String.length()`) to determine whether what's left is an 8-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to extract 8-digit numbers from a text String, then you can do that as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d{8})\\b").matcher(
                "Hello 12345678 world 23456789");
        while (m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/